# Test in VSCode, prevent test tree from auto-expanding

Tags: user-interface, testing, visual-studio-code

I wonder if there is a setting to prevent the tree with the tests from auto-expanding when running the tests. Only tests that failed should auto-expand.
Or at least a quick way to fold the tree to a given level like the Ctrl+K+1,2,3 shortcut in the editor.